# Android Studio - Incompatible Selected Device

Tags: android

I want to deploy the apps to real device. But it always show the selected device is incompatible. Butt when i try it in emulator it works. Can you help me to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: I think you have to enable developer options on your device, connect it to your PC and tap on "trust" button when displayed on your device.

Comment: Android version of your device is lower than your minSdk. so try run with newer version device or change your minSdk to below 11.

Answer (score 0):

Enable developer options and enable USB debugging

Answer (score 0):

Only  authorized Devices  is used for Debugging via adb. Select ok while asking allow USB debugging with some fingerprints :

[image]

some system will ask only once if Always is checked.